# To find number of $x$ such that $sin(2x)=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To find number of  $x$ such that $sin(2x)=1$ in interval $[-2\pi,2\pi]$. Now i made graph and i found 4 points. But textbook states 2 points. I would like to know where i am wrong? Thanks

Comment: Your textbook is wrong. There are indeed four solutions in the given interval.

Comment: Actually this a part of $$\log_{0.5}sin(x)=1-\log_{0.5}cos(x)$$

Comment: I have to find number of x

Comment: Er... you've got the wrong interval? Should be $[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: One needs to restrict $x$ such that $\sin(x)>0$ and $\cos(x)>0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes i think this happens on extreme left end near -2pi and one at pi/4

Answer (score 0):

This question may better solve algebraically, not graphically.

First we observe the range of the angle: $x\in[-2\pi,2\pi]\Rightarrow 2x\in[-4\pi,4\pi]$.

Then, since $\sin(2x)=1$, then $\displaystyle 2x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

How many $k$ is possible, then that many $2x$ is in $[-4\pi,4\pi]$, then that many $x$ is possible. So we turn to solve this inequality.

> $$\displaystyle -4\pi\leq2x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\leq4\pi$$

**Sol:**
$$\begin{alignat*}{2}&-4\leq\frac{1}{2}+2k\leq4\\
\Rightarrow &-8\leq1+4k\leq8\\
\Rightarrow &-9\leq4k\leq7\\
\Rightarrow &\frac{-9}{4}\leq k\leq\frac{7}{4}\\
\Rightarrow &-2.\cdots\leq k\leq1.\cdots\\
\Rightarrow &k=-2,-1,0,1
\end{alignat*}$$

So four solutions. You're right.